# python qt5 textbox replace how to do

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

[image]

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)

    self.show()
def start(self):
    noalt = self.textEdit.text()
   # addalt = noalt.text.replace("","test")
    #print(noalt)
```

I want to add a specific word to the content I wrote in the first text box so that it can be entered in the second text box.
I've tried many ways, but I can't figure it out. Help me.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @codemu you mean like google translate?

Comment: @lone_coder Yes, it's similar!